# Change Related Products Depending on Size - Magento

Tags: magento

Really hope someone can help point me in the right direction with this, i have been going round in circles for a quite a while.

**Background Info**

i) I have a configurable product with 3 associated simple products (different sizes)

ii) I have some related products that are specific to each size (they are each different prices & simple products also)

iii) I have linked the related products to the relevant different size simple products

*If i go to the simple product directly, the correct related product shows*

**Problem**

How do i make it so on the main configurable product. that when the customer selects the size, that it shows the correct related product to buy with that size? (as Add on Buys)

Comment: I don't believe their is any core behaviour to do this. Since the switching of simples on a configurable page are done via JavaScipt, I guess you'd have to add an AJAX request to fetch the new related products to replace that section of the page.

Comment: like @Cags says, you should get selected product value or id then query the product catalog to get products and finally refresh the related product area by Ajax call. So, there isn't a simple answer to make this.

Comment: I have a link which is get related products from configurable product [How to get a grouped product’s associated products in Magento](http://mikebywaters.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/how-to-get-a-grouped-products-associated-products-in-magento/)